# Identification of script that is being used for maps

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, events, maps

I want to create meetup groups in different countries for my mental health support website.

I've found a site that display a map within a wordpress page (http://www.cleargreen.com/community/practice-groups) where people can create events and manage them themselves, it uses a third party script you have to login to (https://www.cleargreen.com/english/tensegrity/login.cfm?dsplyLanguageID=1).

I was wondering what script they are using? and how did they integrate it so well with wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps api located on https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

And then in wordpress you are probably already using ACF plugin(if not http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

You can create custum field for google maps OR fields with latitude and longitude

Then in your them add

```
       <?php $location = get_field("[YOUR FIELD NAME]", $post->ID); ?>
       <script>
            function initialize() {
                var map_canvas = document.getElementById("[YOURE CONTAINER ID]");
                var map_options = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location["lat"] ?>, <?php echo $location["lng"] ?>),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:  new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location["lat"] ?>, <?php echo $location["lng"] ?>),
                  map: map,
                  icon: '[PATH TO YOUR PIN IMAGE]'
                });
            }


          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```